# iOS Xcode Autolayout Not Filling Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

The auto layout feature in Xcode behaves in random ways, I'm hoping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong here.

When following all guides online about using the Stack View with Autolayout to constrain to nearest margins with 0 and 0 for left / right. Why oh why does this sometimes decide to work correctly and other times not work at all. The Stack View seems to add in margins to the left or right based on where the item is currently positioned within the Storyboard which is not what I told it to do.

I'm sure I must be doing something wrong or clicking in the wrong place. From what I've read online, everything should be working, yet it isn't.

Ideas?

**Update 1,** here's what I have as a structure;

```
 - View
 - - Stack View (Using Auto Layout which works correctly)
 - - - Image View
 - - Stack View
 - - - Scroll View
 - - - - Label
 - - - - Text Field
```

So when I select the second Stack View above (with the scroll view below), then use the Pin tool to set to margins to 0 and 0 on the left/right, the margins end up being 0 and 350 for example. So when this is viewed in the simulator, the Input fields are not within the screen size, they are too big and out.

What should I be doing differently for this? This is the same process I've followed when adding the Stack View / Auto Layout margin settings of 0 and 0 to left/right as I did with the image.

Comment: I'll update main question, formatting is not keeping in here

Comment: Update info in main question

Comment: They are certainly doing that! :-) I'll scrap those. All of the guides I've read on the Auto Layout feature all talk about adding in a Stack View for everything first, which is probably why I've been having so much trouble trying to get the basic layout to work as it should do within the Storyboard. So if I have a form with say 10 fields and 10 titles for those fields, what is the best way to get the Auto Layout feature to work?

Comment: I'm still not getting this at all. The layout I'm after is as follows, an image (full width) at the top (which seems to only work when the Image View is embedded within a Stack View, then the 20x rows (10 labels + 10 Text Fields). Adding in a Stack View seems to sort the layout, kind of, but the Text Fields I want full width and the Labels aligned to the left. I can't see why this is so difficult with Xcode. What should I be clicking to get this to work as it should be doing?

Comment: No, not figured that one out yet. Tried putting the Labels and Text Fields inside the Scroll View, but that didn't work

Comment: I have all of the fields laid out on the Storyboard how I want them to look. It's just when I run the simulator everything messes up, so there must be some settings / structure / layout I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll re-read all the docs on the Auto Layout and Scroll Views etc. There is something that I'm not getting here and it's clearly not just a single setting which I was hoping it would be. I'm used to building responsive websites which just work. It's frustrating that something so simple is proving to be so difficult on Apple and Xcode. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Select the field(s) that are appearing off screen, select the Pin tool, and uptick the 'Constrain to Margins' button. Adjust the details for left/right margins according to your needs within the Pin section. Then follow this guide for how to embed all of this in a scroll view. Essentially, select all items you want included within the scroll view, click the menu item Editor > Embed In > Scroll View. Then select the new Scroll View you'll see within the left hand side of your storyboard, click the Resolve Auto Layout Issues (4th icon on bottom right of Xcode) then click on 'Reset to Suggested Constraints'. You may need to adjust the height of the scroll view on the Story Board by clicking & dragging on the edges to fit the screen depending on the size you're working with.